# Nomenclature question: name for a repeating subsignal with variable period

Tags: signals-history

Is there an agreed upon name for a signal comprised of a repeating subsignal, but the period of the subsignal can be variable?

For example, in an ECG, the subsignal (the waveform for a single heartbeat) is regular and repeats, but the period of the subsignal (the heart rate, RR interval, etc.) varies from beat to beat.

Comment: A warbling signal?

Comment: What's the definition of warbling in signal processing?

Comment: I think what Andy says is "this is not a common case, so you'll have to introduce a term yourself and define it like you just did in your question; "warbling" would be a very intuitive term you could use to describe this kind of signal".

Comment: by the way, your description is um, *very* flexible, because I bet your signal doesn't have a very defined point at which it abruptly changes "speed"...

Comment: So in signal processing, it is often the case that one describes a signal by the dominant characteristic of that signal, as if it were a sound: an impulse, a chirp, a beat, a tone, noise, etc.  A signal that varies back and forth in frequency would correspond to a warble in my mind.  I think the important thing is to convey the property of interest in a way that a large number of people would understand.  Mapping that property to the aural effect it would have on sound is a good way to do that.  Mapping to how it would look if modulating light (pulsing, blinking, strobing, dimming) also works

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @AndyWalls : You should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably call it a

> strongly cyclostationary signal with highly correlated, very significant jitter

or something like that. But that would be a very communications engineering way of looking at it!

As discussed in the comments, it might be better to define a term of your own design that conveys what you (and more importantly, the reader) should associate with the signal.